# Replace with "sed" a character with backslash and use this in a variable

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I have this sting: `the string's problem` and I want to change this to:

```
file 'the string'\''s problem'
```

My code looks like this:

```
newline=`echo "$string" | sed "s/'/'\\\''/g"`
echo $newline | sed "s|$newline|file '$newline'|g" >> "$newPList"
```

But the result from this is:

```
file 'the string'''s problem'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not so complicated

```
$ str="string's problem"
$ sed 's/'\''/&\\&&/g' <<<"$str"
string'\''s problem
$ new="file '$(sed 's/'\''/&\\&&/g' <<<"$str")'"
$ echo "$new"
file 'string'\''s problem'
```

It is critically important to quote the `"$new"` 
variable when you use it.

Comment: Thank you! I saw now that my edited way has not work.

Comment: I see you've never accepted any answer to any of your questions. Please read http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers and learn how the community works.

Comment: Sorry, I will take care of it in the future.

Answer (score 3):

It's a `perl` one-liner, all in one, without additionally string constructions **;)**

```
$ perl -pe "s/^(.*)'(.*)$/file '\$1\'\\\'\'\$2'/" <<< "the string's problem"
file 'the string'\''s problem'
```